# placing .gifs in text

Tags: support

I have read *how to post gifs on this site*, but I can't get that to work for me. I tried using Gfycat and everytime I try and upload the images I get an error saying `This isn't an animated gif`, so I am wondering. How do you all out there record and save them? As I recorded it, used Premiere Pro to convert to Gif and tried that.

Comment: I use [licecap](https://github.com/lepht/licecap) running in wine.

Comment: @gandalf3 what is wine?

Comment: [It's an environment for running windows programs on linux](https://www.winehq.org/about/).

Comment: On gfycat, click the paperclip icon and you should see 4 textareas, the second one has the actual .gif and not the special webm or mp4 format they display by default.

Comment: @gandalf3 worked great! Mind putting that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the error was coming from gfycat, but I'm not sure, as they do allow non-gif uploads (they will convert to a gif automatically).

That said, I normally use [peek](https://www.winehq.org/about/) to capture gifs. I've also used [LICEcap](https://github.com/justinfrankel/licecap) and [gifcam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/) running under [wine](https://www.winehq.org/about/) (wine is not needed if you are on windows).

If the file is < 2MB, uploading directly via the image button or <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> should work fine. If not, try gfycat :)

Comment: perfect! Thanks again

Comment: about licecap on linux (with wine), I have to add that I can't record mouse pointer, though (works on windows), and others too, apparently (http://forum.cockos.com/showthread.php?s=c55575985c70a79e987a0a5fd0ed8bb6&t=181959). Recently I just found key-mon (https://github.com/critiqjo/key-mon), it seems quite useful for tutorial-like screen recording, although that means adding another separate tool...

Comment: @m.ardito Indeed. I've recently discovered [peek](https://github.com/phw/peek), a licecap-like gif recorder with native linux support (and mouse-capturing abilities).

Comment: @gandalf3 yes, I've already seen that, I'll try that on linux, but it seems that it _doesn't_ support it natively...  <<How can I capture mouse clicks and/or key strokes? Peek does not support this natively. But you could install an external tool like key-mon >> that is where I found about key-mon, in fact... :)

Comment: @m.ardito Ah, it doesn't capture *clicks*, but it does capture the *cursor*. There's an [X utility](https://github.com/Carpetsmoker/find-cursor) [someone on unix.se](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183910/highlight-current-mouse-position#comment626154_228674) made which can be made to do mouse click highlighting, and [screenkey](https://github.com/wavexx/screenkey) can show keystrokes. My experience with key-mon was rather buggy, but I've yet to find a really satisfying alternative.