# What is the process for creating gifs for questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, faq, questions, answers

We now have over [1600](http://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/400331) posts with gifs in them, gifs are very popular and useful; however it seems that they can be hard to create.
I have read [placing .gifs in text](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/522/2217) and [How to post gifs on this site?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/404/2217), yet I still have not found a complete write up for how to create and add gifs.

Comment: Yet [another idea.](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/68647/array-not-following-curve#comment118770_68649) This tool is now [here](http://www.screentogif.com/).

Comment: @pycoder I've had that in my [answer](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/964/2217) all along. :) But good piece of software.

Comment: Sorry, didn't check...just saw that comment and wanted to link to it in this thread. ;-(

Comment: I would recommend ShareX. It can take screenshots and capture gifs, but it also immediately uploads them to imgur and provides you a link. With this, you don't have to worry about the SE upload limit because you can just point to the imgur link directly instead of going through the upload dialog.

Comment: @JoshSilveous while that is super convenient. I would urge you to not simply use imgur. All images *need* to be hosted on SE. Now if you can not make the gif under 2mb, that is a different issue, but then and only then should an external host be used.

Comment: @David But StackExchange's host is just a subdomain of imgur (stack.imgur.com). Unless StackExchange gets some kind of priority on imgur, why does it matter? The host is the same, the only difference is that it doesn't use "stack" in the domain.

Comment: @JoshSilveous yes SE uses imgur, but it is very different. Imgur guaranties the the `i.stack.imgur` images will never be deleted. I do not trust them on their regular site.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## The recording software

The top two are by far the most used (on this site):

- [LICEcap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) Windows and OSX installer
- [GifCam](http://blog.bahraniapps.com/gifcam/) Windows only, but no install (yay)
- [ScreenToGif](http://www.screentogif.com) Newer app, looks very good, Windows only, no install (yay)
- [peek](https://github.com/phw/peek/) Linux only

Do note that these all can be run on linux using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/).

There are *many* other ways, such as recording your screen, and then later converting to .gif (and in some cases that is better) but 98% of the time it is *way* easier to just use one of the options above.

## Making the gif

This is the easiest and the hardest part, I'll explain.

All you have to do is hit "Record"
[image: animated gif of making an animated gif]

1. But then you messed up one of the steps in blender you were trying to show off. *(start again)*
2. You forgot to turn on [Screencast Keys](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Screencast_Key_Status_Tool), or [KeyCastOW](https://brookhong.github.io/2014/04/28/keycast-on-windows.html) (both how I display the key presses). *(start again)*
3. You realize half way through that you are only recording half of the 3D view. *(start again)*
4. You took *way* too long, and now have a 20mb gif. :( *(start again)*
5. Blender crashes. *(start again)*
6. Things that never go wrong (when you JUST made that exact same thing) go wrong now that you are recording a gif. *(start again)*

So it is easy to record a gif, it is hard to get it right.

You will quickly gain a new appreciation for all those that make hour long tutorials. I digress, back to the gifs.

### Reducing the Size

You want to aim for the smallest file size possible. The three parts of that are how big you make the gif, how long, and what FPS.

I (almost) always use 15 fps.
I (almost) always make my gifs 650px by 400px.
As short as I can make the gif without making it unclear what is happening.

This is **NOT** how you want blender to look when you are making a gif.
[image: gif recording]
It is very hard to keep all actions in the gif capture window.

Instead change blender to look something like this:
[image: blender set up for gif recording]

Now everything you do in the 3D view will be recorded.

## Publish on BSE

The biggest reason to aim for a small file size (under 2mb) is so you can use stack exchange's built in image upload and hosting.

If you do have a gif under 2mb then you can add it to your question or answer like any other image. By using the add image button, or simply pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>.
[image: add image button]

However if it is over 2mb, then you will have to change the gif to get it under the 2mb limit. Crop it, if there is extra space in the gif that really does not need to be there - crop it out. Try different compression settings (I've found screenToGif has pretty good compression) that is the next easiest. If the gif looks too poor at the lower quality, then change the number of colors and re-record. If you reduce the variety of colors, the file will get smaller.

Please do not use an external image host. Even if you answer looks a tad better now with the uncompressed gif, eventually your answer will be broken. And dead links are worse than deleted default cubes.

Comment: Great post. I mention in *Solution 2* [here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/608/12) that both licecap and gifcam can run under wine on linux.

Comment: Also, you want to make sure that you enable *capture cursor* if you want to make your mouse show in the gif   (as in here) http://i.stack.imgur.com/9LUMe.gif

Comment: Note that both Gifcam and LICEcap will work on linux via wine. Some of Gifcam's options will not be available, but basic operation will be fine.

Comment: +1 for the "making the GIF" process!  I just spent 5 hours failing at making a simple screen recording to send to a friend and I think every one of those happened!  I'm also interested to see those other recorder options too as LICEcap doesn't work properly on my tablet.

Comment: So I've tried all three, LiceCAP works fine on my workstation but not on my Surface tablet, GifCam and ScreenToGif both work fine.  ScreenToGif has a lot more features (including saving to a video file), but makes the computer lag a little while recording (doesn't affect the recording though).

Comment: My favorite GIF capture application is Gyazo. You can do screenshots and GIF capture, and it instantly uploads it to the web when you take it. Then just copy/paste the URL into SE.

Answer (score 11):

You can make gif's using blender and GIMP.

Three ways you can get original frames from blender -

1. Render an animation. Depending on what you want to show you can setup an animation in blender and render the animation to images. You can also use the viewports opengl render option.
2. Accumulate a series of screenshots. Blender can take a screenshot of it's window. Take a screenshot at each stage that you want to display in the gif.
3. Make a [screencast](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/info/screenshot.html#screencasts). Blender can also automatically take a series of screenshots as you perform your task. There are settings in [preferences](https://www.blender.org/manual/preferences/system.html#screencast) under system to adjust the framerate of a screencast. The screenshots will be saved based on your render settings for location and filetype.

[image: window menu]

Making the gif -

Once you have a series of frames to use for your gif, you can open them in gimp. By using *File->Open As Layers...* you can select multiple images and have each one added as a new layer. Note that this will add the selected images to the current image so you may want to close all open images before doing this.

[image: gimp - open as layers]

Select and crop the image to the area you want in the gif. To reduce the filesize of the gif use *Filter->Animation->Optimise (for GIF)*. This removes duplicated areas from each layer, leaving them mostly transparent and the result is opened in a new image.

[image: optimise menu]

Then export the image and give it a `.gif` suffix and you will get the options dialog for saving the gif, be sure to enable "as animation".

[image: gif options]

The gif's you save can then be added to your answer the same as any other image.

Comment: Could you show how you can change the delay between frames by editing the layer name. I always optimise (difference) must do a test one day.

Comment: You can rename the layer to customise the delay of each frame - it will have `(100ms)` in the name. If you want the same delay for each frame you can change the export settings for delay and tick `Use delay entered above for all frames` which will override the delay in the layer names.

Comment: According to the [gimp docs](http://docs.gimp.org/2.8/en/plug-in-optimize.html) optimize (gif) also reduces the size of the layer.

Answer (score 9):

There's definitely not a single best process. I hope this thread fills up with people weighing in on their method.

**Linux here.. (Ubuntu) -- not crossplatform**

My solution involves a few prerequisits

- (optional) Kazam, you could use Blender's Screencast to create *.png
- Blender's VSE, <sub>(hah! you totally have this already!)</sub>
- [FFmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/)'s for the `convert` command,
- [gifsicle](https://www.lcdf.org/gifsicle/) "command line automated gifs",
- A Blender add-on called [BCPrompt](https://github.com/zeffii/BlenderConsolePrompt) (disclaimer I wrote this add-on).

---

The instructions don't quite capture how simple this is to do :)

- use Kazam (screencapture software with UI) to record a selected screen area to a `.mp4`. (hit start, do your thing, hit stop, save to `.mp4`)

  - When you make mistakes you can undo, or restart the demoing without restarting the kazam recording.
- Import the `.mp4` to Blender's VSE, and edit it till it shows only the  most essential frames.
- Now I'm ready to render the clip as a set of .pngs, but first I need to set the correct render dimensions and the *start* and *end frame*. With the strip/meta strip active I got to console and execute a few commands included with the BCPrompt add-on.

  ```
  >>> dandc     (ctrl+Enter is mapped to execute a command from console)
  ```

  the `dandc` commands does these two things for you:

  1. sets render-output's width and height from active strip's dimensions.
  2. sets start and end-frame from active strip's extents.
- Render the VSE to `*.png` to some `/Path/to/folder/` either via UI or

  ```
  >>> anim /Path/to/folder/
  ```
- Once the render is complete I execute

  ```
  >>> ogif /Path/to/folder/ 256 24
  ```

  this outputs two animated gifs of the `*.png` in that folder

  - 1 non optimized called `animated.gif`
  - 1 optimized to 256 colors and 24 fps called `opt_256_animated_24fps.gif`
- To get the generated gif into the browser I can execute system commands from the python console using an exclamation to prefix the line. (this turns the pyconsole into a lightweight terminal)

  ```
  >>> !nautilus /Path/to/folder/
  ```

  will open nautilus at the given folder and I can drag the     optimized.gif to the BlenderStackExchange window.

Comment: ffmpeg is [also capable of producing gif files](http://blog.pkh.me/p/21-high-quality-gif-with-ffmpeg.html) using the palettegen and paletteuse filters.

Comment: @Skrylar yep https://gist.github.com/zeffii/59d1e1b3ebbab0d75438 -- I may still use that , thanks for the reminder.

Comment: The convert command is [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org), not FFMpeg

Answer (score 2):

I use regular screen capture tools (anything to make a video), then upload the video to [ezgif.com](https://ezgif.com/).

I currently switch between Quicktime and Monosnap (but I'm on a Mac). They both work well, but for different situations. Then I upload the result to ezgif for editing and "gif-making." This site lets me optimize with compression, cutting, frame rate, etc., and does it all rather quickly.

Let me know if you want more details, or a gif of the process :-)

Answer (score 1):

Still working in 2.92:

To convert an existing image-sequence or movie-file, the **[Bligify](https://github.com/doakey3/Bligify)** add-on wraps **ImageMagick** and **Gifsicle**, and can be called from inside the VSE. You must give it the paths to those executables in its set-up panel.

At least, on Ubuntu, the .blend, with the paths set, must be saved as a startup for the paths to persist between sessions, unless you want to go in and tweak the script.

Answer (score 0):

I use `byzanz` which is in the **ubuntu** repos, along with [byzanz-record-window](https://gist.github.com/lucy/3042755)

A quick search also yields [this](https://github.com/syohex/byzanz-window), which I haven't tried.

If you prefer a graphic method there's also [silentcast](https://github.com/colinkeenan/silentcast) but I find its UI a bit confusing.

Another solution is using the internal blender screencast command, saving the output to ogv and using the script in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/298656/26889) to convert to gif

Or render to png's and use

```
convert -delay 10 -loop 0 *.png -layers OptimizeFrame animation.gif
```

to convert to gif, and

```
gifsicle -O3 animation.gif --colors 256 -o out.gif
```

will optimize a bit further