# How do I attach files in comments and sub-comments?

Tags: support

I can't find a way to attach files (specifically rendered videos .mkv or "FFmpeg" in blender) to my comments. I'm new to the site so it might actually be really obvious.

Comment: What do you mean by "mkv or "FFmpeg" in blender"? Do you expect them to be a part of your .blend file? The only files expected to be attached on the site are .blend files which help to narrow down the problem and should not be the only definition of it (tldr add screenshots and description). Files of other formats are not attached and shouldn't be. To quickly illustrate something you can use .gif or link to YT video with description.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner at blender and this website. I meant **rendered videos**. Is there a way that I can add **rendered videos** from my computer to my comments?

Comment: The same principle applies - only files applicable for showcasing the question are expected. .blend files as priority together with images and description. Any videos are large for download and can't be embedded in the posts, only usual links to external resource. It would maybe add clarity if you [edit] and write *why* do you need to add videos to question or comment.

Comment: I need to attach the files to showcase a graphics/lag error **after** a 5-hour render, which is why I won't upload a .blend file (I don't even know how to). I think I could do a .gif, but I'm not sure how to record and upload one. I use OBS for recording, but I don't think it can record in .gif. I could do a YT vid, but it seems like a .gif would be easier.

Comment: You could always make some screenshots on the frames where "graphics error" is visible and include them. I don't see why not posting a file just because it renders slowly; though the .blend attached should have minimal example allowing to reproduce the problem (only one object / action / strip etc). See [how to record gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/963/1245)

Comment: Ok, thanks! (comment too short)

Comment: and if you really need to show a video, external solutions are there. Youtube as example. Or google drive, or openload, ... For animation reviews (meaning there is a need to review frame per frame, anotate on frames, etc), there are some specialized websites, like syncsketch.com