# Animated gifs of Blender

Tags: discussion

I see a lot of questions and answers posted here with animated gifs of various sections of the viewport attached to them. Can anyone tell me how this is done? Does it involve a 3rd party application or is there an addon I can use with Blender?

Comment: Hello, there are several apps to make animated gifs, if this is what you're looking for. I'm personally using Screen To Gif

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/ https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-to-post-gifs-on-this-site/405#405

Comment: There are also online video to gif converters for free