# Upload images in comments

Tags: discussion

How do I upload an image from desktop to this site to reply on a comment?

Can someone share the steps and share the necessary links?

Comment: Depends on the operating system. On Windows, you can install "ShareX", press "PrtScr" key, drag a rectangle over the screen, wait until you hear a ding, then in your comment paste the link using CTRL+V shortcut.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491 https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/ https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/404/how-to-post-gifs-on-this-site/