# I wanna upload Blender screenshot videos here. What are the best open source screen capture programs for Windows 11?

Tags: discussion

I wanna upload Blender screenshot videos here. What are the best open source screen capture programs for Windows 11? Is a GIF recorder good?

Comment: ScreenToGif works fine

Comment: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/522/placing-gifs-in-text https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers/964#964